# Gracefully bubble up with a clicktarget

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working with this plugin that runs off of the data attribute.  Basically when you click anywhere on the body it will determine if the click target has this specific data-vzpop.  The problem is lets say I have a div and inside the div is an a href.  It only acknowledges the a href as the click target and not the div (which makes sense).

What I want to try and do in some cases is put the data attribute on the containing div that way anything within the div works on click.

Here is a sample of the issue with jsfiddle it requires viewing the console so you can actually see which element is registered as being clicked.

```
<div data-vzpop>
    <a href="#">Click Me</a>
</div>

$('body').on('click', function(evt){
    var clickTarget = evt.target;
    if ($(clickTarget).attr('data-vzpop') !== undefined){
        evt.preventDefault();           
        console.log('called correctly')
    }  else {
        console.log('not called correctly')
    }
    console.log(clickTarget)
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt3u8/1/)

Comment: Try clicking to the right of the href...looks like the code still fires, because the div extends all the way to the right. Do you have a more specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use Event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-vzpop]', function(evt) {
```

This will only trigger when the `evt.target` has a data attribute of `data-vzpop`, no matter the value.

If you want items inside the `[data-vzpop]` to trigger it as well, you would use your original click event but check that the `$(clickTarget).closest('[data-vzpop]').length > 0` to determine if it's a nested target.

```
$('body').on('click', function(evt){
    var clickTarget = evt.target;
    if ($(clickTarget).attr('data-vzpop') != null ||
        $(clickTarget).closest('[data-vzpop]').length > 0){
        evt.preventDefault();           
        console.log('called correctly')
    }  else {
        console.log('not called correctly')
    }
    console.log(clickTarget)
});
```

Comment: This solved the issue it seems.  I will have to run more tests in the actual code that this was based on.  Thank  you.